# Enable Instant in Chrome browser using custom search engine

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

I used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/468794/why-does-google-chrome-ignore-last-known-google-url-property-in-local-state) hack to ignore my country location by google chrome default search engine. So far, it has worked at least in Chromium browser, but with the version **20.0.1132.47**, it does not work anymore.

So now, the next option is to use a custom search engine, but with that, the **Instant** search does **not** work.

It is possible to enable Instant in Chrome browser using custom search engine?

Comment: Does google.com/ncr work?

Comment: No, it does not.